# ¿Puedo tener instalado PyQt4 y PyQt5 a la vez?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt4

tengo instalado PyQt5 en mi computadora, pero muchos proyectos me dicen que me sale mejor desarrollarlos con PyQt4, soy aprendiz intermedio, y me gustaria saber si puedo instalar PyQt4 sin perder PyQt5. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sí, sí puedes, son 2 librerias distintas. Por ejemplo yo tengo instalado PyQt4, PyQt5, PySide y PySide2 en python2 y python3. :P

Comment: Woow Gracias. Perdona mi ignorancia, pero de qué tratan PySide y PySide2? @eyllanesc

Comment: y cual me recomiendas que sea la mejor forma de instalar PyQt4?

Comment: Igual que PyQt4 es un wrapper de Qt4 y PyQt5 lo es de Qt5, ambos son creados por: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com, PySide lo es de Qt4, y PySide2 de Qt5 generado por Qt de forma oficial, yo prefiero usar PyQt. instalalo igual que instalaste PyQt5